# Using an allocated space to store multiple arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, c11

Is the following correct code?

Assume it is known that all object pointer types have equal size and alignment, with size not greater than 8.

```
// allocate some space to A, and set *A and **A to different regions of that space
char*** A = malloc(92);
*A = (char**)( (char*)A + 2*sizeof(char**) );
**A = (char*)*A + 4*sizeof(char*);

// initialize the second char** object
A[1] = *A + 2;

// write four strings further out in the space
strcpy(A[0][0],"string-0-0");
A[0][1] = A[0][0] + strlen(A[0][0]) + 1;
strcpy(A[0][1],"string-0-1");
A[1][0] = A[0][1] + strlen(A[0][1]) + 1;
strcpy(A[1][0],"string-1-0");
A[1][1] = A[1][0] + strlen(A[1][0]) + 1;
strcpy(A[1][1],"string-1-1");
```

I find stuff like this useful in situations where it may not be straightforward how to deallocate the object. For example, say A[1][1] may or may not be reassigned to the address of a string literal. Either way you just free A. Also, the number of calls to malloc are minimized.

My concern that this may not be correct code is based on the following. Using a draft version of the standard, I have:

> 7.22.3 Memory management functions
>
> 1. ...The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated)...

So I am garanteed to be able to use the space as an array of a single type. I can not find any garantee that I can use it as an array of two distinct types (char* and char**). Note that the use of some of the space as char arrays is unique given that any object can be accessed as a character type array.

The rules for effective type are consistent with this approach, as no individual byte is ever used as part of two different types.

While the above indicates there seems to be no explicit violation of the standard, the standard does not explicitly permit the behavior either, and we have paragraph 2 of chapter 4 (emphasis added):

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ **or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior**. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’.

That is a little vague when the memory model itself is so vague. The use of space returned by malloc() to store an array of any (one) type is apparently in need of explicit allowance, which allowance I quoted above. So one could argue that the use of that space for disjoint arrays of distinct types also requires explicit allowance and, without it, is left as undefined behavior per chapter 4.

So, to be specific, if the code example is correct, what is wrong with the argument that it is not explicitly defined and therefore undefined, per the part of chapter 4 from the standard that is above quoted?

Comment: `char*** A = malloc(90);` is wrong with a pointer size of 8

Comment: @4386427, thanks, I was a little hasty on my arithmetic.

Comment: @4386427, I am getting 6 pointers of size 8 have size 6*8=48 and 4 strings of length 10 make 44, 48+44=92.

Comment: You realize that C has `struct`s?

Comment: @4386427, how do strict aliasing rules  hurt me here?

Comment: @EOF, this is a simplified example, there are situations where I find this type of approach a lot more clear and less cumbersome than structs. Also, in a struct approach, it would be harder to be able to replace some strings with strings that shouldn't be freed, and then have a simple and efficient way to free the master object at the end.

Comment: @Kyle: Well, I find this needlessly convoluted. Also, `*A = (char*)A + 2*sizeof(char**);` is a constraint violation. `*A` is of type `char**`, `(char*)A + 2*sizeof(char**)` of type `char*`.

Comment: @EOF, thanks, I'll correct that violation.

Comment: `malloc(92)` hurst my eyes. Don't do that ever. Really. `malloc` that is used to initialize a non-`char` pointer should always have a `sizeof` expression as an argument.

Comment: This code is really obscure. Don't do fancy three star programming, simply allocate a plain array. If a 2D array of strings is what you want, then allocate one by using an array pointer: `char* array (*)[y] = malloc( sizeof(char*[x][y] ); ... free(array);`. Then allocate the individual strings separately, based on their length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the offset of any object from the start of the allocated region is a multiple of the alignment, and provided that no piece of the memory is used as more than one type within the lifetime of the allocation, there will be no problem.

One nasty gotcha is that while there are some algorithms (e.g. for hash tables) that will work very nicely with a table that is initially filled with arbitrary values (given a value that may or may not be correct, code may be able to determine whether the value is correct much more quickly--O(1) vs O(N)--than it could find the correct value without an initial guess), such behavior may not be reliable when using gcc or clang.  The way they interpret the Standard, writing memory as one type and reading as another non-character type yields Undefined Behavior even if the destination type would have no trap representations, even if pointers are converted which are converted to a new type are never used (in their original form) after that, and even if code would work correctly for any value the read might have yielded in cases where the data had not yet been written as the new type.

Given:

```
float *fp;
uint32_t *ip;

*fp = 1.0f;
*ip = 23;
```

Behavior would be defined if fp and ip identify the same storage, and the
storage would be required to hold 23 afterward.  On the other hand, given:

```
float *fp;
uint32_t *ip;

*fp = 1.0f;
uint32_t temp = *ip;
*ip = 23;
```

a compiler could take advantage of the Undefined Behavior to reorder the
operations so the write to *fp occurred after the write to *ip.  If the data is getting reused for something like a hash table it's unlikely that a compiler would be able to usefully apply such optimization, but a "smart" compiler might reorder writes of useless data past the writes of useful data.  Such "optimizations" aren't terribly likely to break things, but there is no Standard-defined way to prevent them except by either freeing and reallocating the storage (if one is using a hosted system and can tolerate the performance hit and possible fragmentation) or else clearing the storage before re-use (which may turn O(1) operations into O(N)).